# Using API behind Cloudflare using HTTP Post and Requests library

Tags: python, web-scraping, cookies, python-requests, cloudflare

I am a little new to Python but an expert at the Mathematica (Wolfram) language so not too much of a noob programmer.  I do a lot of website scraping and have been successful at it.  Recently, a website that I had successfully scraped changed and now I can't use their API.

In general, when using (scraping) an API, my methodology was to open Chrome and use the inspector to find the XHR calls.  Then copy that call as cURL and then translate it using this [site](https://curl.trillworks.com/) to a python Requests call.  This has worked like magic in the past even for sites that are behind cloudflare.  For sites behind cloudflare, I would log in manually and copy the cookie into the code.  This always worked until this site changed their code.

I did that process and my python Requests code is below.  I am trying to scrape the https://sportsbet.io/sports website.  This particular call is to get all the basketball leagues.

```
import requests

headers = {
    'authority': 'sportsbet.io',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'authorization': '',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'origin': 'https://sportsbet.io',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'referer': 'https://sportsbet.io/sports/basketball/inplay',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9'
    }

data = '${"operationName":"SportEventListQuery","variables":{"language":"en","site":"sportsbet","slug":"basketball","timePeriod":"LIVE","leagueTournaments":"LIVE","featuredLeagueTournaments":"LIVE","tournamentEventCount":"LIVE"},"query":"query SportEventListQuery($language: String\\u0021, $slug: String\\u0021, $timePeriod: SportsbetNewGraphqlSportLeagues\\u0021, $leagueTournaments: SportsbetNewGraphqlLeagueTournaments\\u0021, $featuredLeagueTournaments: SportsbetNewGraphqlFeaturedLeagueTournaments\\u0021, $tournamentEventCount: SportsbetNewGraphqlTournamentEventCount\\u0021) {\\\\n sportsbetNewGraphql {\\\\n id\\\\n getSportBySlug(slug: $slug) {\\\\n id\\\\n featuredLeague {\\\\n id\\\\n name(language: $language)\\\\n tournaments(childType: $featuredLeagueTournaments) {\\\\n id\\\\n name(language: $language)\\\\n eventCount(childType: $tournamentEventCount)\\\\n league {\\\\n id\\\\n name(language: $language)\\\\n __typename\\\\n }\\\\n __typename\\\\n }\\\\n __typename\\\\n }\\\\n name(language: $language)\\\\n leagues(childType: $timePeriod) {\\\\n id\\\\n name(language: $language)\\\\n slug\\\\n tournaments(childType: $leagueTournaments) {\\\\n id\\\\n name(language: $language)\\\\n eventCount(childType: $tournamentEventCount)\\\\n __typename\\\\n }\\\\n __typename\\\\n }\\\\n __typename\\\\n }\\\\n __typename\\\\n }\\\\n}\\\\n"}'

response = requests.post('https://sportsbet.io/graphql', headers=headers, data=data)
print(response)
```

I get 403 errors.  Looking for a little guidance on how to use (scrape) this API.

Comment: somtimes it is good to use `requests.Session()`  and run `get()` with original page - to get fresh cookies which can be needed in finall `post()`.

Comment: I try to open this URL in web browser but it doesn't open. Maybe it is only temporary problem or maybe it doesn't like connection from some countries - so at this moment I can't see what can be the problem with your code.

Comment: @furas try to open https://sportsbet.io/es/sports yes, I believe there are country restrictions but a VPN can take care of that.  I don't think the get() will work as I am not trying to get the whole page but going straight to the API that serves the data.  They recently changed something where I can't directly access the API anymore.   Thank you for the help!

Comment: when web browser sends request to API it may also send cookies which it get with main page - and API may also check these cookies. And this is why I suggested to use `get()` to get cookies. APIs which are officially avaliable for user they may not check cookies but APIs which are not avaliable for user they may check cookies to block all bots/spams/hackers/